# How to combine simple with statement and recurcive statement in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In your SQL statement, you can aggregate some statement into with statement e.g

```sql
with first_ds as (
    ...
), second_ds as (
    ...
)
select * from second_ds;
```

But how to combine statement with recursive e.g:

```sql
with first_ds as (
    ...
), 
RECURSIVE second_ds_rec as (
    -- init part
    select 
        1 as level, 
        f.* 
    from first_ds f
    ...

    UNION 

    -- recursive part
    select 
      f.level + 1, 
      f.* 
    from first_ds f
    join second_ds_rec rec on ...
    ...
)
select * from second_ds_rec;
```

Every time with this construction I have got exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RECURSIVE` keyword should be moved to the first cte:

```
with RECURSIVE  first_ds as (
    ...
), 
second_ds_rec as (
    -- init part
    select 
        1 as level, 
        f.* 
    from first_ds f
    ...

    UNION 

    -- recursive part
    select 
      f.level + 1, 
      f.* 
    from first_ds f
    join second_ds_rec rec on ...
    ...
)
select * from second_ds_rec;
```